# AWS Athena only return the first value of my JSON content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have this JSON content on S3 `{"foo":"anything", "bar": true }{"foo":"anything", "bar": false }...`

My query to make the Athena Table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.sample (
  `foo` string,
  `bar` boolean,

  ) PARTITIONED BY (
  year string,
  month string,
  day string,
  hour string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://bucket/sample/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

when i make the query to athena

```
SELECT * from db.sample
```

It's only return the first value of my content `column foo = anything, column bar = true`

I can't get the two or more values to show at same time.

I already use `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'ignore.malformed.json' = 'true')` and the problem continues.

Comment: New records need to start on a new line. Your data seems to be all on a single line.

Comment: How can i change that? My firehose get my JSON record and put all data on S3.

Comment: I suggest you check how the data is being sent to Firehose. Is your system sending Firehose a {Single JSON record} at a time, or multiple records at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently stumbled across this issue. As others mentioned, each new record should start or end with a new line. This seems an undocumented behavior of the Serde serialization lib used by was (org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe).

My code snippet looks like this:

```
for record in event['records']:
    payload = base64.b64decode(record['data'])
    payload = json.loads(payload)
    # Do custom processing on the payload dictionary here
    new_payload = json.dumps(payload) + '\n'
    new_payload_bytes = new_payload.encode()  # b64encode requires bytes not string
    output_record = {
        'recordId': record['recordId'],
        'result': 'Ok',
        'data': base64.b64encode(new_payload_bytes)
    }
    output.append(output_record)
return {'records': output}
```